# How to show only Standard Format post in my custom taxonomy page -wordpress 3.8.1

Tags: customization, taxonomy, post-formats

I want to exclude photo and video categories (ID's 1 and 2 respectively) from my custom taxonomy page.

Any suggestions on how can I exclude these two categories from the loop?

```
<?php
/**
 * Locations taxonomy archive
 */
get_header();
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="primary-content">
        <h1 class="archive-title"><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?> News</h1>

        <?php if ( !empty( $term->description ) ): ?>
        <div class="archive-description">
            <?php echo esc_html($term->description); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post clearfix'); ?>>
            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <div class="content clearfix">
                <div class="post-info">
                    <p><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
                </div><!--// end .post-info -->
                <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content( __('Full story…') ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--// end #post-XX -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('« Previous Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries »') ?></div>
        </div>

        <?php else: ?>

        <h2 class="post-title">No News in <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></h2>
        <div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="entry">
                <p>It seems there isn't anything happening in <strong><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $term->name ); ?></strong> right now. Check back later, something is bound to happen soon.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!--// end .primary-content -->

    <div class="secondary-content">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div><!--// end .secondary-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your comment, photos and videos aren't custom post types but actually categories. I'm changing my answer to reflect your comment.

You can use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to exclude specific categories in your loop. You can achieve that with `$query->set( 'cat=-1,-2,-3' );` This will exclude categories with ID's 1, 2  and 3, and will only show categories with ID's other that 1, 2 and 3.

Just remember, to exclude categories, you have to use the minus(-) sign in front of the category ID.

Here is the complete code that should go into your functions.php to exclude your categories on your taxonomy page

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_tax() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-2,-3' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```